# How do I subtract these two columns in SQL and make an extra column that shows the difference?

Tags: sql, subtraction, domo

| Begin_Term | End_Term |
| --- | --- |
| 2018 | Current |
| -select- | Current |
| 2015 | 2019 |
| -select- | 2018 |

I used using the `case when SUM('End_Term') - SUM ('Begin_Term) then 1 else 0  end` but it only shows 0's and 1's for the results. I'm also using DOMO so the SQL formatting is alot different.

Comment: This makes no sense. you can't sum a varchar column and why do you expect a case expression that returns a 1 or 0  to somehow not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does selecting a new column that merely subtracts the two columns (e.g. `SELECT 'End_Term' - 'Begin_Term' AS Diff`) mostly meet your needs?

As comments indicated, 3 of the 4 sample rows you gave are not reasonable to expect to process, since the columns do not both contain numbers.

If you have special case strings like "Current" and "-select-" that you wish to convert to numbers, then I suggest you will want to do this first, and then do your math second.

For example:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 'End_Term' = "Current" THEN year(CURDATE()) ELSE 'End_Term' as 'End_Term'
```

My understanding is that DOMO handles type casting / conversion transparently behind the scenes so there's no need to actually worry about whether the column itself is a varchar.

I'm not sure what "-select-" is meant to be. It seems to me like erroneous placeholder form data that shouldn't have ended up submitted or inserted into your database in the first place.